# Flex child of child does not expand to 100%

Tags: html, css, dom, flexbox

In CSS, if a child of a child is set to `width: 100%` and the wrapping div has `display: flex` set, the content does not expand to 100% it only uses the space of the content.

How would one make it expand to the size the grandchild sets itself but still use flex?

flex-grow is probably not the answer since this will always expand to take up the full space and not respect the size the grandchild sets itself.

See following example:

```css
.wrapperFlex, .wrapperBlock{
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.wrapperFlex {
  display: flex;
}

.levelOne {
}

.levelOneGrow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.levelTwo, .levelTwoFullWidth {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.levelTwoFullWidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.levelOnePassthrough{
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<!-- Premise -->
<div class="wrapperFlex">
  <div>PRE</div>
  <div class="levelOne">
    <div class="levelTwoFullWidth">
      WRAPPER FLEX
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>AFTER</div>
</div>
<br/>

<!-- Not what is wanted, the grandchild here does not actually expand to 100%
it should be only as wide as the content here -->
<div class="wrapperFlex">
  <div>PRE</div>
  <div class="levelOneGrow">
    <div class="levelTwo">
      WRAPPER FLEX GROW
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>AFTER</div>
</div>

<br/>

<!-- What is wanted but not possible, display: contents is not commonly available -->
<div class="wrapperFlex">
  <div>PRE</div>
  <div class="levelOnePassthrough">
    <div class="levelTwoFullWidth ">
      WRAPPER FLEX PASSTHROUGH
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>AFTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The "grandchild" does not set the width on its own, when you put in `100%`, it means take the full width of the parent, and since the parent (`levelOne`) is not taking the full width of its own parent, then it and its child do not expand to the full available width. You have to set `.levelOne { flex-grow: 1; }` for this to work.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi this does not work, I updated the question with an example

Comment: "WRAPPER FLEX GROW" and "WRAPPER FLEX PASSTHROUGH" examples look identical, and you're esaying that the latter is what you desire to have, so I'm a bit confused as to why you think `flex-grow` is not what you want.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi they are visually identical, but they are not the same.
Passthrough is really just that, it uses display: contents to bubble the width
And in the grow example the grandchild does not have a width of 100%

Comment: So if I understand correctly (correct me if I'm not), you want the same exact desired behavior to be achieved by doing `.grandchild { width: 100%; }` instead of `.child { flex-grow: 1; }`. Is that true? And if it is, why does it matter so much if they're both doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you set flex-basis to the child?

```css
.wrapperFlex, .wrapperBlock{
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.wrapperFlex {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapperBlock {
  display: block;
}

.levelOne {
  flex-basis: 100%; /* Set flex-basis to 100% */
}

.levelTwo {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperFlex">
  <div class="levelOne">
    <div class="levelTwo">
      WRAPPER FLEX
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="wrapperBlock">
  <div class="levelOne">
    <div class="levelTwo">
      WRAPPER BLOCK
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set .levelOne {width:100%} ,if im not misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the flex property as one to the child i.e `levelOne` like this `flex:1;`.
It will work properly as you check here.

```css
.wrapperFlex, .wrapperBlock{
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.wrapperFlex {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapperBlock {
  display: block;
}

.levelOne {
flex:1;
}

.levelTwo {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperFlex">
  <div class="levelOne">
    <div class="levelTwo">
      WRAPPER FLEX
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="wrapperBlock">
  <div class="levelOne">
    <div class="levelTwo">
      WRAPPER BLOCK
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with more info, flex-grow is not an option I think